# Karate match two JSON files: array of objects which contains inner shuffled arrays of object

Tags: arrays, karate

**Task:**

Have 3 endpoints:

1st returns random data for request to two other endpoints.

Two other endpoints operates with different DBs but on, more or less, similar data.

I need to validate that response from one endpoint is matching response from another, both endpoints send the same data but in different order.

e.g.:

endpoint 'A':

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "field1": 111,
      "array1": [
        {
          "field11": 102,
          "field22": 231
        },
        {
          "field11": 103,
          "field22": 231
        },
        {
          "field11": 102,
          "field22": 256
        },
        {
          "field11": 104,
          "field22": 256
        }
      ],
      "field2": 122,
      "array2": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "field1": 211,
      "field2": 222,
      "field3": 233
    }
  ]
}
```

endpoint 'B':

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "field1": 211,
      "field2": 222,
      "field3": 233
    },
    {
      "field1": 111,
      "array1": [
        {
          "field11": 104,
          "field22": 256
        },
        {
          "field11": 102,
          "field22": 256
        },
        {
          "field11": 103,
          "field22": 231
        },
        {
          "field11": 102,
          "field22": 231
        }
      ],
      "field2": 222,
      "array2": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**endpointA_response.items contains only endpointB_response.items** verification fails because it considers inner **array1** from one response doesn't match **array1** from another response because array items are in different order.

**endpointA_response.items[0].array1 contains only endpointB_response.items[1].array1** works OK though, but it is not what I need. I need to compare whole response regardless of ordering.

Is there any possibility to apply **contains only** verification to array of objects which contains arrays which could have items in different order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `endpointA_response.items[0].array1 contains only endpointB_response.items[1].array1`

> I need to compare whole response regardless of ordering.

Then you have to do some "extra" work. There is no magic.

I would suggest sorting. In Karate 1.0, there is a `karate.sort()` API. For example, if you are sure that the value of `field1` is a unique-identfier

```
* def expected = karate.sort(responseA, x => x.field1)
```

Then hopefully it aligns things so that you can do a contains match.

Read this answer for other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120851/143475